# 'Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto.' Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

tengo este problema hace dias, y aun no encuentro respuesta a esto en especifico. Me tira este Error: 'Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto.'

```
    Public Function homeCargar()        
If Session("logueado") = 1 And Session("Type") = "CL" Then
            Try
                ForClint.Attributes.Add("style", "display:")
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox("Fallo: " + ex.Message)
            End Try
        End If

    End Function
```

La idea es cuando la paganía hace el pageLoad haga esto:

```
If Session("logeado") = 0 Then
            ForClint.Attributes.Add("style", "display:None")

        End If
```

Y cuando el cliente se loguee se elimine el Display

Comment: probablemente es porque las sesiones no están llenas . en que momento llenas las variables sesión ?

Comment: Las lleno cuando cuando el cliente hace el inicio de sesión, una vez que se loguea se llenan varias variables, 
If datos.Rows.Count = 1 Then
                    Session("logueado") = 1
                    Session("Cliente") = usu
                    Session("Type") = "CL"
                    Response.Redirect("/pages/PagClientes/informacionGeneral.aspx")
Este es un pedacito del código porque es bastante largo, pero específicamente aquí se llena esa variable.

Comment: antes de validar si la sesión tiene valor, valida : If (Session IsNot Nothing)